# Use htaccess to mask few urls

Tags: .htaccess

How can I use htaccess to redirect a few static pages and keep the same url?
Example :

```
Redirect www.mydomain.com/url-that-remains.php to www.mydomain.com/page-number-23
```

My current htaccess file looks like that:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code should work:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^url-that-remains\.php$ /page-number-23 [L,NC]
```

Comment: I do not know why it is not working. I've updated my question with the code that's already in my .htaccess file.

Comment: Put this rule: `RewriteRule ^url-that-remains\.php$ /page-number-23 [L,NC,R]` just below `RewriteBase` line.

Comment: It redirects me, but its also changes the URL.

Comment: Nah, I was trying to redirect it to a already rewrited URL, that was the problem. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule /somestaticpageonyourwebsite.html /yournewpage.html [R=302]
```

**EDIT:**

I don't know why the above doesn't work. This should work.

```
RedirectPermanent /somestaticpageonyourwebsite.html /yournewpage.html
```

Comment: Mod Rewrite surely works, but your instruction doesn't. When I access the first link it not getting me the content of the second url. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Well, your new code redirects the page to the real one, but I need to keep the first URL and only get the content of the second page.

Comment: Now both codes work, but it still just redirects to the new page and is not keeping the old url. Maybe I need to change flags or something? The code looks like that ``RewriteEngine On RewriteBase / RewriteRule termeni-si-conditii.php termeni-si-conditii-27 [R=302]``

Comment: `is not keeping the old url` , You mean that you want to retain what you typed(old url) in the address bar ?

Comment: Yes. I want to access ``termeni-si-conditii.php`` and get the content of ``termeni-si-conditii-27`` without changing the url.

Comment: You want "rewrite", not "redirect".   Redirect instructs the browser to fetch a different URL, rewrite returns different content for the requested URL.